# How to send 2 query sets in a django CBV(ListView)

Tags: python, django, listview, django-class-based-views

```
class myView(ListView):
    template_name = "myView.html"

    def get_context_data(**kwargs):
        queryset = people.objects.all()
        queryset2 = people.objects.filter(stage = 4)

        context = {
            'paginator': None,
            'page_obj': None,
            'is_paginated': False,
            'object_list_all': queryset,
            'object_list_4': queryset2
        }

        context.update(kwargs)

        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(myView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

`

I am getting the following error: `myView` must define `queryset` or `model`. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to make this a ListView. The only thing a ListView does is generate an object_list context item from the model or queryset attributes. If you don't want that, just make it a standard TemplateView.

Comment: What are the benefits of a ListView or an UpdateView?

Comment: I just said what the benefit of a ListView is. An UpdateView, not surprisingly, is to display and process a form to update a single item.